# validate only alphabets using shell script in busybox

Tags: sh, openwrt, busybox

I want to validate a string which should only be Alphabets (Capital/Small). I can do it in Linux easily using Bash or Shell, but not able to validate in Busybox (OpenWRT). My piece of code is 
...

```
#!/bin/sh
. /usr/share/libubox/jshn.sh
Info=$(cat /root/Info.json)
json_load "$Info"
json_get_var value plmn_description
echo "$value"
if [[ "$value" == [a-zA-Z] ]] ;then
    echo "Valid"
else
    echo "Invalid information"
fi
```

...

Comment: Could you olease post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Here it is the json. {
        "registration": "registered",
        "plmn_mcc": 410,
        "plmn_mnc": 6,
        "plmn_description": "Telenor",
        "roaming": false
}

Comment: This code should be displaying output "Valid" as you can see plmn_description value is "Telenor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [case conditional construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) like this:

```
case "$value" in
  *[!a-zA-Z]*) echo invalid information ;;
            *) echo valid
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Busybox awk:

```
$ busybox awk '{              # using busybox awk
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++)         # iterate all json record fields (not the last, thou)
        if($i=="\"plmn_description\":" && $(i+1)~/^\"[a-zA-Z]+\",?$/) {
            ret="Valid"       # if "plmn_description": is followed by "alphabets"
            exit              # exit for performance 
        }
}
END {
    print (ret?ret:"Invalid") # output Valid or Invalid
}' Info.json                  # process the json file
```

Output:

```
Valid
```